# Spring data Mongo with QueryDSL- return custom dto instead of actual documents

Tags: spring-data-mongodb, querydsl

**Scenario
========**

Find and return dto (not actual document)  from Mongo DB using SpringdataMongo and QueryDsl

**scanario**

### document

Customer{
name,
age,
city,
zip
}

**JPA repository**

interface CustomerQuerydslRepository
extends CrudRepository<Customer, String>, QuerydslPredicateExecutor { }

**Service Call**

{
...
@Autowired CustomerQuerydslRepository repository;

List result = repository.findAll(QCustomer.customer.lastname.eq("Matthews"));

}

since my original document is large, I want to return only few fields and needs that to be mapped to a dto below

### dto

CustomerDto{
name,
age
}

my current workaround is to map returned documents to dto in the service layer but looking for more optimized ways using QueryDSL itself.